# Balancing distribution of two datasets by exchanging samples

Tags: distributions, optimization

I have fun little problem that I want to try to solve. I've been given a dataset which I will randomly split up into two sets. But now I want these two sets to have the same distribution.

Consider the following two randomly generated datasets:

A:

```
#1: 3     7     3
#2: 3     7     3 
#3: 1     1     1
```

B:

```
#1: 2     2     2
#2: 2     2     2
#3: 1     1     1
#4: 1     1     1
#5: 2     2     2
#6: 3     7     3
#7: 1     1     1
#8: 2     2     2
#9: 3     7     3
```

**EDIT**

I want the means over the classes to be as similar as possible. Currently the means are as follows:

```
A := [2.3,  5,   2.3]
B := [1.9,  2.7, 1.9]
```

But by moving one sample between them, A(#1 or #2) <-> B(#1 or #2 or #5 or #8), the means become

```
A := [2.0,  3.3,   2,0]
B := [2.0,  3.3,   2,0]
```

The reason I want this is, for some classes, the randomized split-up dataset is quite different. Don't get me wrong, its quite good, but I started to wonder if I could make the split even better. I currently do this by randomly switching images between dataset, calculate the norm distance between the means (as in, I use the means as vectors) then keep that exchange if the norm distance goes down. But this made me wonder if there was a better approach to this possible.

<strike>I want essentially to be able to calculate, that by exchanging A(#1 or #2) <-> B(#1 or #2 or #5 or #8) will give me the same distribution over both sets. Note that this is just a sample case, in real life the datasets can be as big as 40.000+ and generally can never have exactly the same distribution.</strike>

I am planning on using this method for balancing datasets for deep learning.

Best regards,
Adam

Comment: In your real dataset, are there also three features per data-point? Are the feature values small integers as well?

Comment: If you're randomly sampling they should have the same population distribution. i.e. you already seem have what you appear to be asking for. Can you clarify what you mean by "same distribution", then?

Comment: In my real dataset, I have up to 40 features per data point, and they are not equal. In the toy example you can think of it like "In each sample, I have M classes, and of those classes there are N instances".

To answer your question @Glen_b, you are right that when I randomly sample my dataset, the distribution becomes similar, but for classes that are rare, it can happen that said class only exists in Set A, if you get really unlucky.

Comment: 1. So you're seeking not the same population distribution (in which that problem you describe should certainly happen sometimes or you don't have random samples from the same distribution), but instead want something about the *samples* to be the same or nearly the same. That's a quite different question and you need to be quite precise about what property (or properties) you want the samples to actually have. 2. Are all your actual features categorical or some measurements, counts etc?

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you for giving my question a consideration, much appreciated :) 1. I won't have any power over how the samples (i.e rows) look, but I can move complete rows between datasets. The basic property I want to achieve is that the mean, over all rows in each column, to be the as similar as possible for all datasets. 2. My features are actually the pixel count of a certain class in an image. So in the toy example (A, #1)  we could think of it as 3 pixels are cars, 7 pixels are animals and 3 are sky for example.

Comment: Sorry, we're using different terminology; I should have matched yours. What I am calling "samples" you're calling datasets (nothing wrong with that usage, it may be better). Thanks for putting this information in your question already.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to minimize differences in means and variance between cohorts, I suggest you look into this publication:

http://www.nathankallus.com/papers/ThePowerOfOptimization.pdf.

It is a very interesting read!

He also published the code:

http://www.nathankallus.com/papers/powerofoptimization.py.txt

Nathan Kallus investigated this further (papers are on his website).

Comment: Very interesting! It seems to try to tackle exactly my issue! I'm going to take a look :)